# Paperclip one type of attachment not being uploaded to S3, others are?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a class, called Report, and Reports are generated via a Rake task. I also use Paperclip for images (user avatars), and it uploads to my S3 bucket fine. Here is the top of the Report model:

```
require 'csv'
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :csv_file, :category

  Paperclip.interpolates :category do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.category.downcase
  end

  has_attached_file :csv_file, 
    path: (Rails.env.staging? || Rails.env.production?) ? ":class/:category/:basename.:extension" : ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:category/:basename.:extension"
```

And my Paperclip.rb file is this:

```
Paperclip.options[:log] = false
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = if Rails.env.dev?
  "/usr/local/bin"
else
  "/usr/bin"
end

PAPERCLIP_OPTIONS = {
  :hash_secret => "HASHSECRETHERE",
  :default_url => "http://placehold.it/:style",
  :processors => [:thumbnail]
}

PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_OPTIONS = if Rails.env.staging? || Rails.env.production?
  { :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/apis/s3.yml",
    :s3_permissions => :public_read,
    :s3_protocol => :https,
    :path => ":class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:hash.:extension" }
else
  { :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:hash.:extension",
    :url => "/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:hash.:extension" }
end

PAPERCLIP_OPTIONS.merge!(PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_OPTIONS)
```

It saves the reports to:

`/system/reports/csv_files/000/000/002/original/general-report-2013-9-25-T-3-56-PM.csv?1380142571`

rather than S3 like my avatars:

`//s3.amazonaws.com/production/media/avatar-placeholder.gif`

Anyone see why?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your environment does not have `RAILS_ENV` (or `RACK_ENV`) set, so your `rake` task is being run in the `development` environment, which does not save to s3 because of this line :

```
PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_OPTIONS = if Rails.env.staging? || Rails.env.production?
```

You probably want to run your `rake` task like this:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake do_some_thing
```

Comment: The environment was set, the options were just being overridden so to fix it I had to merge the path in.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by merging the options into PAPERCLIP_OPTIONS like so:

```
  has_attached_file :csv_file, PAPERCLIP_OPTIONS.merge(
    path: (Rails.env.staging? || Rails.env.production?) ? ":class/:category/:basename.:extension" : ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:category/:basename.:extension",
    processors: []
  )
```